Attempt to read property "week_id" on null
I am building a school management system I want once a teacher gets to the time table section they will be able to see the subjects they are teaching that day and they should also see the room and time but I am receiving this error 'Attempt to read property "week_id" on null'
the following are the codes
 static public function getMyTimeTable($class_id, $subject_id)
    {
        // return self::where('class_id', '=', $class_id)->delete();
        $getWeek = week1model::getWeekUsingName(date('1'));
 return ClassSubjectTimetable::getRecordClassSubject($class_id, $subject_id, $getWeek->week_id);

    }

this line of code is the one supposed to access the week id but its returning null
 $getWeek = week1model::getWeekUsingName(date('1'));

the following models are working together with the above model
week1 model->this model is supposed to fetch the name from the week table by comparing the name received from the model above
static public function getWeekUsingName($weekName)
    {
        return week1model::where('name', '=', $weekName)->first();
    }

classsubjecttimetable model
 static public function getRecordClassSubject($class_id, $subject_id, $week_id)
    {
        return self::where('class_id', '=', $class_id)->where('subject_id', '=', $subject_id)->where('week_id', '=', $week_id)->first();

    }//

the blade file
@foreach ($getRecord as $value)
    <tr>
        <td> {{$value->id}}</td>
        <td> {{$value->class_name}}</td>
        <td> {{$value->subject_name}}</td>
        <td> {{$value->subject_type}}</td>
        <td>
            @php
                $ClassSubject = $value->getMyTimetable($value->class_id, $value->subject_id);
            @endphp
            @if(!empty($ClassSubject))
                {{date('h:i A', strtotime($ClassSubject->start_time))}}
                to {{date('h:i A', strtotime($ClassSubject->end_time))}}
                <br>
                Room number::{{$ClassSubject->room_number}}
            @endif

        </td>
        <td> {{date('d-m-Y H:i A', strtotime($value->created_at))}}</td>

        <td>
            <a href="{{url('/teacher/my_class_subject/timetable/' . $value->class_id . '/' . $value->subject_id)}}"
                class="btn btn-primary">My
                TimeTable</a>
        </td>

    </tr>
@endforeach

I am trying to display the current day subjects to be taught the time and roon number

You are passing this date('1') as a parameter to this getWeekUsingName($weekName). Are you sure that format of the passing parameter is correct?

how should i do it

return week1model::where('name', '=', $weekName)->first(); -> you need to make sure that there is an actual row of data returned in this eloquent. Otherwise, it will return null.

Not really sure what you are trying to do, date('1') returns 1. Are you trying to get the name of the week of today? https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5UpNzshXSEksSdVQN1TXVNBTCPAIiHf197FW0NdX8CvNTUotUjBEUZaDoSwnvxyoKjmxOFUhJ7WkBMjOAQA%2C&v=8.2.20

If you are trying to get the day of the week by passing an int value, then you have a better change of doing it with an array instead.

@Allan , can you tell us which data type you have used for name of the week1model model? And also provide an example of real stored data in the name field of week1model so that we can check the format of stored value in the name field.

@Subha i have used String/varchar example 'monday'

@Allan, date('1') will returns Monday not monday, this might be a reason you are getting null because it doesn't match data stored in the table.Check that.

@Subha I have changed but its not working still

@Mr.Kenneth its supposed to return the current day

@Allan,What error currently you are getting ? just a note it should be date('l')(lower case l) not numeric 1.I have mistakenly placed 1 just because i copied from your code.

@Allan. as per what Subha said, it should be date('l') the same with the link I provided. Since you are expecting lower case monday then you would need strlower(date('l'))
